# passing many .gp files to gnuplot vs. repeatedly passing one file

Tags: gnuplot

With `gnuplot` 5.2 patchlevel 6 and `bash`, in a folder with several `.gp` files which I create programmatically:

When I execute `gnuplot *.gp` gnuplot tells me `Need full using spec for x time data` for the 7th file and aborts.

When I execute `ls *.gp | while read fn; do gnuplot $fn; done` there's no error message and all plots are created.

The gnuplot command in question is

```
plot $TimesData using 3:xtic(1) title "{/*0.6 Title 1}" lc rgb "#0000E0",\
     $TimesData using 4 title "{/*0.6 Title 2}" lc rgb "#00A000"
```

Isn't the behaviour supposed to be identical? What am I missing?

Comment: I guess the information you provided is not enough to easily reproduce (i.e. copy&paste&run code) your issue.
When and how do you define/assign `$TimeData`? Are you sure that it is the 7th file or could it maybe be that is actually is the 2nd file just with index 7? My suspicion would be that `$TimeData` is not defined after the 1st run.

Comment: @theozh Thank you for your suggestions. Not sure what you mean by file index; it's simply the 7th file that's interpreted. `$TimeData` is of course defined in the same file, or else `gnuplot` would yield an error when the file is intepreted by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ways you are calling gnuplot are different, and can very well create different results.

`gnuplot *.gp` starts a single gnuplot session in which all commands from the first file are executed, then from the second one and so on. Any settings that were changed by the first file are still different from default during the execution of the second file! Depending on what exactly is written in your script files, weird interference may occur.

`ls *.gp | while read fn; do gnuplot $fn; done` iterates through all files and starts a new gnuplot session for each of the files, making all gnuplot calls independent from each other.

Therefore your second approach is the correct solution to your problem, although you could try to put `reset session` at the first line of each script file, run `gnuplot *.gp` and see what happens.